# verifying for duplicate values for a property using typescript interface

Tags: typescript

is there anyway in typescript to validate an interface object property to take only unique values ?

example:

```
interface MyElement{
   id: number
}

let element1 : MyElement = {
   id: 100
}

let element2 : MyElement = {
   id: 100  //here i would like typescript to show an error saying duplicate ID at compile time
}
```

as both element1 and element2 are using same interface "MyElement" i thought we could impose some check on MyElement itself.
i am new to typescript and any clue would really help me.

Comment: How is this a duplicate exactly? These are 2 separate objects, also typescript can't check for value collisions in compile time, you would need a dependently typed language for that.

Comment: okay then my question is to check for value collisions in compile time. like how qml does for its components.
any reference you would reccomend to create dependently typed language extension in vs code for typescript.?
thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about global constantly initialised objects? Does that mean you just need to be able to compare the ids locally in your app? Why even use manually specified ids?

Comment: yes i need to compare the id's locally at compile time.
to be accurate id's are not really numbers but strings in my application. i want them to be unique in order to access an object in another object. so we assign meaningful names to id. and use this id to access few properties from one object in another.

Comment: for example, el1 = { type:"textinput" , id:"text1"}. el2 = {type:"span" , innerText: "$text1.text"}. here el2 which is a span tag accessing text of el1 using el1's id "text1".

Comment: @AyyappaGollu Why not declare the interface in lowercase `interface MyElement{...`?  Like the convention https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 1):

While TypeScript compiler can check literal values, it's ability to do that is limited. You cannot make it validate substrings, so it won't help you with checking the `test1` part in the `$text1.text` string.

Nevertheless, it is still possible to limit values for certain fields, like `innerText`, with help of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). You just need to let TSC know that some fo your values are actually types. So the suggestion is to make TSC aware of your IDs and make them a type.

This means removing the `id` field from `MyElement`, introducing a single type which purpose is to keep all the unique elements in your application. The code that operates on `innerText` field would also need a revamping because of changed value format.

```js
class Elements {
    text1: MyElement = {
        type: 'textinput'
    };

    theNicestSpan: MyElement = {
        type: 'span',
        innerText: 'text1'
    };
}

// This is how you turn a set of properties into a type.
// This means that variables of type ElementID may only have values
// which are names of fields in the Elements class.
type ElementID = keyof Elements;

// Enumerating possible element types as well to get compile-time checks for those as well.
type ElementType = 'textinput'|'span';

class MyElement {
    type: ElementType
    innerText?: ElementID // innerText can only be either 'text1' or 'theNicestSpan'
}

const elements = new Elements;
elements.theNicestSpan; // Use your elements...
```

Another possible approach would be to just enumerate possible ID values:

```js
type ElementID = 'text1'|'theNicestSpan';
```

But that seems less flexible to me than having them stored in a collection class.

Comment: thank you for your response. it's very ellaborative. i will try it out and let you know how it worked out.